# Can I remove gcc compiler after tensorflow installation?

Tags: tensorflow, gcc, infrastructure

I'm sorry if this is not the right place to ask this.  If it is not, let me know and I'll close this question.

I'm trying to set up an environment for a bot we are working on, and part of that will require installing gcc on a server so we can install tensorflow.  However, my company has decided that compilers are unsafe, so part of the process for production will require removing the compiler from the server after a set amount of time. After tensor flow is installed, will it be safe to remove the gcc compiler from the server, or will it break my installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that tesnorflow itself does not invoke gcc during operation, it should be safe.  Unless shared libraries tensorflow depends on are removed with it (can happen if you system packages them as part of the gcc package -- e.g. `libstdc++`, `libgomp`, etc).

I'd recommend checking tensorflow executables with `ldd -r` to find out (after removing gcc -- or query the package manager whether any of the output libraries is owned by the gcc package).